# jsPDF returning blank page

Tags: javascript, jspdf

The variable `finalPestsTable` is a html table with perfect syntax (have tested that). When the code runs a new tap opens with a completely blank output.

```
let finalPestsTable = `
        <table class="table" id="pdf_pests_table">
          <tr>${pestTableHeadings}</tr>
          ${pestTableBody}
        </table>
      `;

      let pdf = new jsPDF({
        orientation: 'p',
        format: 'a4'
      });
      pdf.fromHTML({
        source: finalPestsTable
      });
      pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue before, the work around is by doing this:

```
window.open(doc.output("bloburl"), "_blank");
```